# Read data from string XML with node enabled false

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

i have an xml string and i want to read data from it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Tree AllowNodeEditing="True" ShowLineImages="False" CheckBoxes="True"
      EnableAjaxSkinRendering="False" AutoPostBackOnCheck="True" AutoPostBack="True">
  <Node Enabled="False" Text="Geen afbeeldingen aanwezig" 
        Checked="True" Selected="True" thumb="" tekst="" />
  <Node Text="IMG_2807 (Small).JPG" 
        Value="../../CMS/Images/Fotogalerie/552/IMG_2807 (Small).JPG" tekst="Afbeelding IMG_2807 (Small).JPG" 
        thumb="../../CMS/Images/Thumbs/552/IMG_2807 (Small).JPG" />
```

please note that in third line Node `enabled=False`.

I am using the code

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(strFile);
                    var values = (from f in doc.Elements().Descendants()
                                  select f.Attribute("Value").Value).ToArray();
```

and this throws an error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to null check the value because if you do `select f.Attribute("Value").Value` without null checking, it will throw an exception if the element doesn't have the `Value` attribute.

Looking at your sample XML not all `Nodes` have the attribute `Value`.

Try this instead:

```
var values = (from f in doc.Descendants("Node")
              where f.Attribute("Value") != null
              select f.Attribute("Value").Value).ToArray();
```